# Error with hibernate + Facelet JSF Managed Bean

Tags: hibernate, jsf

I read [this tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html). I try, but i get error. We have Mysql and netbean 7.0.1. A table with name : "customer", columns : "id int, name varchar, email varchar, description varchar". I used Hibernate to mapping table.  This is my model class :

```
 /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package model;

import domain.Customer;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

/**
 *
 * @author xuanhung2401
 */
public class CustomerModel {
    
    Session session = null;
    
    public CustomerModel(){
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    }
    
    public List<Customer> getAllCustomer(int startId, int endId){
        List<Customer> list = null;
        try{
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            Transaction ts = session.beginTransaction();
            Query query = session.createQuery("from Customer");
            list = (List<Customer>)query.list();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }
    
    public Customer getById(int id){
        Customer c = new Customer();
        try{
            Transaction ts = session.beginTransaction();
            Query query = session.createQuery("from Customer as c where c.id = "+id );
            c = (Customer)query.uniqueResult();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            
        }

        return c;
    }
    
    public boolean updateCustomer(Customer c){
        try{
            Transaction ts = session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(c);  
            ts.commit();
            return true;
            
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }       
    }
    
    public boolean addCustomer(Customer c){
        try{
            Transaction ts = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(c);            
            ts.commit();            
            return true;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }        
    }
    
    public boolean deleteCustomer(Customer c){
        try{
            Transaction ts = session.beginTransaction();
            session.delete(c);
            ts.commit();
            return true;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my controller :

```
   /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package controller;

import domain.Customer;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.model.DataModel;
import javax.faces.model.ListDataModel;
import javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletContext;
import model.CustomerModel;

/**
 *
 * @author xuanhung2401
 */
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class CustomerController {

    CustomerModel model;
    DataModel customers;
    Customer currentCustomer;
    /** Creates a new instance of CustomerController */
    public CustomerController() {
        model = new CustomerModel();
    }
    
    public DataModel getCustomers(){
        if (customers==null) {
            customers = new ListDataModel(model.getAllCustomer(1, 3));
        }
        return customers;
    }
    
    public void recreateModel(){
        customers = null;
        
    }
        
    
    public Customer getCurrentCustomer(){
        if (currentCustomer==null) {
            currentCustomer = new Customer();
        }
        return currentCustomer;
    }
    
    public String editCustomer(){
        int id = 0;        
        try {
            id = Integer.parseInt(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id")) ;        
            currentCustomer = model.getById(id);
            if (currentCustomer!=null) {
                return "edit";
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            
        }                
        return "myTemplateClient";
    }
    public String editProcess(){  
        try{
            model.updateCustomer(currentCustomer);
            recreateModel();
        }catch(Exception ex){
        
        }        
        return "myTemplateClient";
    }
    
    public String addCustomer(){
        currentCustomer = new Customer();
        return "add";
    }
            
    public String addProcess(){   
        if (currentCustomer!=null) {
            model.addCustomer(currentCustomer);                     
            currentCustomer = new Customer();
            recreateModel();
        }        
        return "myTemplateClient";
    }
    
    public String deleteCustomer(){
        int id = 0;        
        id = Integer.parseInt(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id")) ;        
        currentCustomer = model.getById(id);
        model.deleteCustomer(currentCustomer);
        recreateModel();
        return "myTemplateClient";
    }
    
    public String goIndex(){
        return "myTemplateClient";
    }
    
    public String prepareView(){
        currentCustomer = (Customer) customers.getRowData();
        if (currentCustomer !=null) {
            return "details";
        }
        return "myTemplateClient";
    }
    
   
}
```

As you see, we have 4 view : myTemplateClient.xhtml, add.xhtml, edit.xhtml, details.xhtml. i navigate by " return "viewname"; " command. Problem are :

1. Address bar is not the same address with page i am viewing. Example : i'm reading myTemplateClient.xhtml, but address bar is : localhost:8080/iDo_Hibernate/faces/details.xhtml ( it must be : localhost:8080/iDo_Hibernate/faces/myTemplateClient.xhtml). After that, when i jump to add.xhtml, address bar is : localhost:8080/iDo_Hibernate/faces/myTemplateClient.xhtml.
2. After i add new customer, it's redirect to "myTemplateClient" page ( this is index page, it shows all customer) with address bar is :  localhost:8080/iDo_Hibernate/faces/add.xhtml. Now, when i refresh my browser, it adds more customer with the same information. I try to clear added object, but still error.

   Please help me fix that errors (Forgive me because my English is not good). Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the issue with urls is because you are using `forward` to navigate between pages. Use `sendRedirect` instead. More information here: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=181

Comment: Because i think we're using hibernate and Facelet, so we'll not use servlet to be a controller. Can you show me more details, i'm just newbie in java. Thank you !

Comment: I think i fixed it. Thanks for your help. 

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("faces/myTemplateClient.xhtml");

Comment: @xuanhung2401 if the answer was helpful to you may mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask